# How to handle "touchend" event in Appium automation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to click a button ("Continue") in a webpage. In automation script .click() operation was performed in that button but it didn't navigate to next page. There is a similar button ("Cancel") for this button .click() executed and it navigated to next page.

Please click on the Hyperlink below for DOM Content

[Continue Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn510.jpg)

[Cancel Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeDiY.jpg)